# What is the warning on ballot contract on remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I start my first development in Solidity
and I use remix and the example files (the ballot)
My first action is compile all exemple file :

- 1_storage.sol
- 2_Owner.sol
- 3_ballot.sol
  For the two first, I 'have no problem,but when I compile 3_ballot.sol I have this warning:
  " compilerMetadata is modifyingcontracts/artifacts/Ballot.json"
  I don't quite understand why I have this message displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Clear you artifacts folder and try compiling again.[image] Right click and choose delete.